# Materialize v1.0.0 hide-on-med-and-down not working in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, materialize

hide-on-med-and-down works fine in firefox 68.0b1 and safari 12.1 which means that with a screen width <= 992px my ul with the class .hide-on-med-and-down is not shown and when > 992px, it is shown as expected. As this menu appears in chrome with another code, it is seems not related to the chrome browser.

BUT **on chrome only**, when the screen is > 992px, **the content of the ul keep not showing**! But with another

I have tried the replace the class hide-on-med-and-down with show-on-large but the result is also unexpected (the ul keep showing on small screen).

```
<nav class="teal">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
       <a href="#home" class="brand-logo">AMV</a>
       <a href="#" data-target="mobile-nav" class="sidenav-trigger>
          <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
        </a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          <li>
            <a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/pages/about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>pages/contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


        <ul class="sidenav " id="mobile-nav">
          <li>
            <a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/pages/about">About</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/pages/contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.js">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidenav').sidenav();
    }); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to the screen who was magnified and I did not care about this parameter. As I reset the zoom to 100%, the menu was showie as expected.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not using variable sign or double quotes for string deceleration in    **`<a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>`**

 
and you have also missed double quotes in **`class="sidenav-trigger>`**

so if you run your code the **sidevav** wont work Anymore

Try **Fixing** **`href`** in all of the **`<a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>`** tag of your **`ul`**

eg. example

```
<nav class="teal">
    <div class="container">
    <a href="#home" class="brand-logo right hide-on-med-and-down">AMV</a>
      <div class="nav-wrapper">

       <a href="#" data-target="mobile-nav" class="sidenav-trigger">
          <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
        </a>

        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          <li>
            <a href="<?php echo "URLROOT"; ?>">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="<?php echo "URLROOT"; ?>">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="<?php echo "URLROOT"; ?>">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <ul class="sidenav " id="mobile-nav">
          <li>
            <a href="<?php echo "URLROOT"; ?>">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="<?php echo "URLROOT"; ?>/pages/about">About</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="<?php echo "URLROOT"; ?>/pages/contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.js">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidenav').sidenav();
    }); 
    </script>
```